# Forgot about an accident when signed up for car insurance. What will the insurance company do if I tell them?

Tags: car-insurance, france

I have moved to France, bought a vehicle and signed up for car insurance. I said that I didn't have any car accidents over the past 2 years, but when I got my letters of experience from my previous car insurance, I saw that one of the letters listed one parking garage single-car accident in the past 2 years, about which I had forgotten. So, now...

- If I tell my new insurance company that I had forgotten about the accident, will it consider me suspicious?
- Would it be better not to have been insured in the past 2 years than to have had a single-car parking accident, from the insurance cost standpoint?

What would you do in this situation?

Comment: Usually the insurance company eventually finds out and adjusts your rates.

Comment: Or they check your record when you have a real claim, and reject it because you fraudulently obtained the insurance in the first place...

Answer (score 1):

Just call your agent and let them know. It's not a big deal if you tell them.   It's a big deal if you try to conceal it, but, you can't, so why invite an accusation of deception?

The only upside you could possibly have if you managed to pull off a deception is a lower rate.  Not worth it.

Anyway I assume you shopped and price-compared for insurance, those results are invalid if you were telling them "no accidents". So if you find the price increase offensive, shop again properly.

Comment: Not that I want to conceal that, but, out of curiosity, why do you think one can't conceal that?

Comment: @sequence because "letters of experience" exist.  What purpose do they serve except to share your history with your next insurer?   If you refuse to turn it over, the insurer will simply assume the worst, right?

Comment: How does the insurer know whether or not there are some letters of experience if one didn't tell one was insured in that period of time in a foreign country?  @Harper - Reinstate Monica

Comment: How do they know? Irrelevant. If you cause an expensive accident, so expensive that they don’t like to pay, they will have ways to find out. Like a list of UK insurance companies and they call anyone on the list.

Answer (score 1):

Copying my answer to the exact same question on expatriates:

If you tell them about the accident, they most likely will adjust your premium accordingly. If you have another accident before you tell them and they find out, you could be in deep trouble; that's a good reason for them not to pay or to recover the money from you.

"Would it be better not to have been insured?" I don't know, but you were insured, and you had an accident, whether you were insured or not, so do yourself a favour and don't try to hide this. The fact is that if you don't tell them, your insurance may be invalid. They will still take your money, they will still pay out third party damage to third parties, but they will ask you to pay the money back if they find out. In addition, you may be “driving without insurance” which would cause you more problems.